# Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy occurs in target 21

Tags: android, api, gradle, target

i have seen this question

[Why Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898857/why-warningunable-to-find-optional-library-org-apache-http-legacy-occurs)

and few more but the problem is not solved , i was using target 23 and i didn't want to , so now when i go back to target 21 i receive this error :

Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

yes i have the optional.json file , yes i have try'd to put the apache in my lib folder but this error still occurs i am stuck on this for far to long .

Comment: checkout this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/32949828/3140227

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this code to your gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Comment: i have no idea why i didn't remember that the compile version can be 23 even the target is 21 , thanks !

Comment: always happy to help .